# I want to put a button in a echo table cell

Tags: php, mysql

Here is part of my php-

```
echo "<table border='0'>";
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $list['SALEPRICE']."</td>";
```

I want to put a button at FOLLOWING BUYURL with link.

```
echo "<td><a target='new' href=\"" . $list['BUYURL'] . "\"><b>VISIT STORE NOW</b></a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: what actually is the question?

Comment: In the cell of the table, where BUYURL IS DISPLAYED, I WANT A BUTTON,WHICH , WHEN CLICKED FOLLOWS THE LINK.

Comment: `target='new'` should be `target='_new'`

Comment: Sorry, you want a link with the dynamic BUYURL column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the  backround-color of the td tag the color of the button and it will give a button effect.

```
<td style=\"background-color: red\"> // Or whatever color.
```

Or put a button inside the td tags

```
<td><button><a href="#">BUYURL</a></button></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop isn't going to work as expected without curly braces following:

```
echo "<table>";
while ( $list = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  echo "<tr>
          <td>".$list['SALEPRICE']."</td>
          <td><a target='_new' href='".$list['BUYURL']."'>Visit Store</a></td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Rather than putting a button in there, make the anchor look more like a button:

```
<style>
  table a {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #555;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 0px #CCC;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: This one is good , but my intention is to put a "button" in place of simple link "BUY NOW"

Comment: yeah, making the anchor look like a button is better.

Comment: @sanjay Use an anchor, that's what it's there for. Use CSS to style it as you like (make it look like a button). This way the visually impaired can still override your anchor styles if they need to, and more.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just do something like this?

```
echo "<table border='0'>";
while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$saleprice = $list['SALEPRICE'];
$buyurl = $list['BUYURL'];

echo "<tr>
     <td>$saleprice</td>
     <td><a target='new' href='$buyurl'><b>VISIT STORE NOW</b></a></td>
     </tr>";
} // end while
     echo "</table>"; // end table since the table was constructed BEFORE the loop
```

for the button

`<button type='button'>VISIT STORE NOW</button>`

or

```
<input type='submit' value='VISIT STORE NOW'>
```

or a standard image or something. Just make sure if you need to use " to escape them \"

Comment: Good idea, my intention is to put a "button" in place of simple link "BUY NOW"